# Need url mod rewrite conditions in .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble getting my `.htaccess` rewrites to work:

1.
http://www.sunfolks.com/ittraining.php
above link is working fine but i want seo friendly url.it Should be: http://www.sunfolks.com/ittraining

2.
http://www.sunfolks.com/ittraining02.php?onlinetraining=java-online-training-in-usa
above link is working fine but i want seo friendly url.it Should be: http://www.sunfolks.com/ittrainings/onlinetraining/java-online-training-in-usa

What are all the changes i have to do for this?

Here's my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^ittrainings/code/([0-9]+)$ ittraining02.php?code=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: I used this code in my htaccess file RewriteEngine On 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^ittrainings/code/([0-9]+)$  ittraining02.php?code=$1 [L]

</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain better next time and provide what you have done that is not working in full details, with some sample outputs.

Why not use something like this and see if it works:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [PT,L]
```

Then have a index.php file that can process the incoming requests using $_GET['url'].

e.g:

```
   $url_args = explode("/", $_GET['url']);
   $section = $url_args[0];
    $category = $url_args[1];
    $data1 = $url_args[2];
```

Then use the variables appropriately in the remainder of your code.

Comment: In index file it is showing empty.Array
(
    [0] => 
)

Comment: If its showing empty, then may be you are not receiving anything from `$_GET['url']`. Take note of the `url` in the last line of the .htaccess file. Lets see what you have done?